# how to set the seekbar handle position to be higher?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, user-interface, seekbar

I have followed [this](http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/02/create-a-custom-styled-ui-slider-seekbar-in-android/) tutorial

I want to use rounded corner bg stripes.

Here are my resources:

[image]

This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <nine-patch
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:dither="true"
            android:src="@drawable/seekbar_idle" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <nine-patch
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:dither="true"
            android:src="@drawable/seekbar_active" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

but yet I have some problems.

(1) How can I make the sides rounded (as in my sources)
even the right side is not rounded enough

[image]

(2) How can I make the handle not partially disappear when at the left most?

[image]

(3) how can I change the size and position of the handle programmatically?

Comment: With regards to point 2) you can set the padding on the seekbar to half the width of the handle (trial and error?) Edit: or setThumbOffset()

Comment: I have tried padding, but it didn't work. I think it means padding for the whole seekbar, and I'm looking for thumb padding only

Comment: try ThumbOffset() maybe? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSeekBar.html#setThumbOffset(int)